# Excel VBA - Delete table (including header and first row)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete a table from Excel including the header, first row and totals.

I have the table name defined as a string (TableName).

I have found

```
Range(TableName).Delete
```

Will delete the DataBodyrange but leave the headings and first row. And

```
Range(TableName).ListObject.Delete
```

Will delete the whole table but leave blank space behind.

What code do I need to delete the entire table and leave no blank space?

Comment: When you say "blank space" do you actually mean it's just not deleting the entire rows of the workbook and shifting the remainder of the rows up?

Comment: Yes.  If the table has 5 rows,  it leaves 6 empty rows behind after the table has been deleted.

Comment: This is what it should do to prevent data lost. Imagine you have 2 tables next to each other, you wouldn't want delete a table will delete all rows which includes 2nd table's data automatically right?

Comment: Understood.  In this case the table has nothing to the right of it. I really do want to delete all rows of the table and bring everything else up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it separately (in fact as far as I can remember, you have to). In my example you don't know the location of the table, but if you do know the starting cell then obviously you can put a constant in instead of firstrow and firstcol.

```
Sub deltable()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim firstrow As Long
Dim firstcol As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim mytable As ListObject

    Set mytable = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table3")

    firstrow = mytable.ListRows(1).Range.Row - 1
    lastrow = mytable.ListRows.Count + firstrow + 1
    firstcol = mytable.ListColumns(1).Range.Column - 1
    lastcol = mytable.ListRows.Count + firstcol + 1

    mytable.Unlist

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(firstrow, firstcol), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Delete shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Good approach, but this can be simplified considerably. Get rid of all `Long` values and instead set a range: `Set delRange = mytable.Range`. Unlist it as usual, then replace everything before the `.Delete` with your set range. It works exactly the same but is a much easier read.

Comment: Many thanks to you both. A great approach and in the end very simple;

    `Set mytable = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table3")
    Set delRange = mytable.Range
    
    mytable.Unlist
    delRange.Delete`